# POST Request flutter return null

Tags: android, json, flutter, api, fastapi

suppose there are 3 integer value (red, green, blue) and the result in String which the prediction after execute the value. I think the problem is the api cannot read String that I had declare in flutter. I have a very difficult to recognise and change the data type in flutter, since controller cannot read integer.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_http_post/rgbModel.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  RgbModel? _rgbcolor;

  final TextEditingController rController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController gController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController bController = TextEditingController();

  Future<RgbModel> createRGB(String red, String green, String blue) async {
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:8000/predict/'),
        body: {"red": red, "green": green, "blue": blue});
    if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 422) {
      final String responseBody = response.body;
      return rgbModelJson(responseBody);
    } else {
      throw Exception("Failed");
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: rController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Value R'),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: gController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Value G'),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: bController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Value G'),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              _rgbcolor == null
                  ? Container()
                  : Text('The prediction ${_rgbcolor?.color}'),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    var rd = rController.text;
                    var grn = gController.text;
                    var bl = bController.text;

                    final RgbModel? usercolor = await createRGB(rd, grn, bl);

                    setState(() {
                      _rgbcolor = usercolor;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text('Post'))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**rgbModel.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';

RgbModel rgbModelJson(String str) => RgbModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String userModelToJson(RgbModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class RgbModel {
  String? color;
  String? red;
  String? green;
  String? blue;

  RgbModel({
    this.color,
    this.red,
    this.green,
    this.blue,
  });

  factory RgbModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => RgbModel(
        color: json["color"],
        red: json["red"].toString(),
        green: json["green"].toString(),
        blue: json["blue"].toString(),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "color": color,
        "red": red,
        "green": green,
        "blue": blue,
      };
}
```

> in debug console vscode dont give a error conclusion of my code.

Unfortunately,the flutter return null

[image: Unfortunately,the flutter return null]

I use FastAPI, this is the API response give the value that I want after execute the value red, green, blue. The return was rgb value ("black")

[image: I use FastAPI, this is the API response after execute the value re,green,blue. The return was rgb value ("black")]

Comment: The problem is your response only have `prediction' key, but when convert it to `rgbModel` model, you try to get `color`, `red`, `green` and `blue` key. it always be `null`

Comment: can you explain more, i dont get it?

Answer (score 0):

Your API return a data like `{"prediction" : "black"}`

Your way to handle it is call `rgbModelJson(responseBody)`

The function will call this

```
factory RgbModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => RgbModel(
        color: json["color"],
        red: json["red"].toString(),
        green: json["green"].toString(),
        blue: json["blue"].toString(),
      );
```

In this function, it try to find the keys `color`, `red`, `green` and `blue`,
while there is the only the `prediction`. Therefore, `json["color"]` ,`json["red"]` ,`json["green"]` ,`json["blue"]` will get `null`. It means that you use the returning data to create a object but all its parameter are `null`.

When you try to get `Text('The prediction ${_rgbcolor?.color}')` in screen, it will always `null`.

I have two ways to solve it:

The first one is change function like:

```
factory RgbModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => RgbModel(
        color: json["prediction"],
        red: json["red"].toString(),
        green: json["green"].toString(),
        blue: json["blue"].toString(),
      );
```

but when your try to get like `_rgbcolor.red`, it will still be null. In case you need the value, you may use the value from textEditingController to change it.

The second one is change your API return format like

```
{
    "color" : "black",
    "red" : 0,
    "green" : 0,
    "blue" : 0,
}
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion,but the output remain same :(

Comment: is it possible the API return the data or status code is not like the picture show. Do you mind try print out the response like change `final String responseBody = response.body; return rgbModelJson(responseBody);` to `final String responseBody = response.body; print(responseBody); return rgbModelJson(responseBody);` and show it in the question.

Comment: The error given after I try your suggestion `I/flutter ( 8774): {"detail":[{"loc":["body"],"msg":"value is not a valid dict","type":"type_error.dict"}]}`